# How do i code an exception in a list in python?

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a news aggregator that scrapes headlines from NY Times using BeautifulSoup4.

I want to include the first 15 elements with an h3 tag on the site. However, the 9th element with a h3  tag on NY Times is an advertisement.

How can i inlude that out?

Heres my code:

```
ht_r = requests.get("https://www.nytimes.com/")
ht_soup = BeautifulSoup(ht_r.content, 'html.parser')
ht_headings = ht_soup.findAll('h3')
ht_headings = ht_headings[0:15]
ht_news = []
```

I have tried to do

```
del ht_headings[9]
```

However, I am getting this error:

SyntaxError: cannot delete function call

Comment: Are you sure you didn't write `del ht_headings(9)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
ht_headings = ht_headings[:9] + ht_headings[10:]
```

Comment: Also consider @Barmar 's comment on question. This error you're getting is resulted because of using `del ht_headings(9)` instead of using `del ht_heading[9]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just loop through a list like this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ht_r = requests.get("https://www.nytimes.com/")
ht_soup = BeautifulSoup(ht_r.content, 'html.parser')
ht_headings = ht_soup.findAll('h3')

output = []
i = 0 

for heading in ht_headings:
    if (i != 9 and i < 15):
        output.append(heading)

print(output)
```